# How to split number into digits and add, then split, and add, etc

Tags: python

```
num = 15

split = ([int(single) for single in str(num)])

total = 0
iteration = 0

while iteration < len(split):
    total = total + split[iteration]
    iteration += 1

print(total)
```

I'm trying to write this program where an input is given (ex. 74837)
The number would be split into individual digits within a list [7,4,8,3,7]
It would then be added (29), then split again [2,9], and then added again until the sum is under 10, so 11, [1,1], finally turning into 2 as the final number

Any help would be awesome. :)

I think that I've figured out splitting and adding, but splitting and adding again until below 10, is confusing me.

Comment: Please show the code you’ve built with the research you’ve carried out.  Happy to help with any *specific* problems.  Interesting algo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [no good faith effort to attempt to solve the question has been shown, and the question is overly broad without such information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: What is the expected output of the algo?  Sure it’s not just convert the number until less than 10.  It is a counter, to determine how many iterations were required?

Comment: This kind of reduction is commonly used in numerology.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple while loop:

```
n = 23452436
while n >= 10:
    print(n)
    n = sum(int(i) for i in str(n))
print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a suitable place to use a recursive method.

```
def digit_sum(n: int):
    curr_sum = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(n))
    if curr_sum < 10:
        return curr_sum
    else:
        return digit_sum(curr_sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun iterative way to do it without any string conversion:

```py
num = 15
def boilItDown(num):
    while num >= 10:
        total = 0
        while num:
            d, m = divmod(num, 10)
            num, total = d, total + m
        num = total
    return num
```

Test code:

```py
print(boilItDown(15))
print(boilItDown(155))
print(boilItDown(1555))
print(boilItDown(15555))
print(boilItDown(155555))
print(boilItDown(1555555))
print(boilItDown(15555555))
```

Output:

```
6
2
7
3
8
4
9
```